# Android thread.start() and runOnUiThread(thread);

Tags: android, multithreading, button

What's wrong with this code?  When I implement it like this, my app works properly.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textout);
        IPAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIPAddress);
        Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        Button buttonSet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set);
        textIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
        buttonSet.setOnClickListener(buttonSetOnClickListener);


        Thread myThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                runClient();
            }// end method run
        };// end myThread
    }// end method onCreate
```

but when I implement it this way.  It force closes:

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonSetOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            myThread.start();
        }// end method onClick
    };
Thread myThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            runClient();
        }// end method run
    };// end myThread
```

I was able to try this but it changes the logic of the program:

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonSetOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            runOnUiThread(myThread);
        }// end method onClick
    };

    Thread myThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            runClient();
        }// end method run
    };// end myThread
```

The first code runs myThread once the onCreate() is called.  The problem is I want to run myThread once a button is pressed.  But doing this results to a force closed.  What causes this force close and what should I do to run a thread once a button is pressed?

Comment: There is no Thread.start call in the first, that way in cannot run your thread. It just creates an instance of the thread. It's OK to start thread from onClick. But you should post your logcat messages or else it's almost impossible to find out the error cause.

Comment: @slkorolev Oh yes, sorry I forgot to add the myThread.start() on this post but when I was testing it I have that line in my program.  I actually do not know how to have my logcat messages yet.  How is it done with eclipse?

Comment: You have a special logcat view in Eclipse. Normally it's located under the code window. Look for LogCat tab title. If you maximaize it you can find error messages with exception stack.

Comment: I had this error I think:

11-20 09:07:50.352: WARN/System.err(2562): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
11-20 09:07:50.370: WARN/System.err(2562):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
11-20 09:07:50.380: WARN/System.err(2562):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:347)
11-20 09:07:50.390: WARN/System.err(2562):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)

Comment: Are modifying the UI in any way inside the runClient() method?

Answer (score 0):

Time/resource intensive operations should not be performed on the UI thread. So `runOnUiThread(myThread)` is probably not a good idea.

Also, UI cannot be manipulated on some other thread.

I think you ought to use `AsyncTask` interface.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html